# MVVM multiple presentations for same object?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I need to present an object differently, twice.

1. as a node in a TreeView (navigation/rename)
2. as 2 TextBoxes (rename/edit content)

```cs
public class Item
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Content{get;set;}
}
```

My first solution was to keep things simple:

```cs
public class MainViewModel
{
    // collection of items (treeview navigation)
    public BindingList<ItemViewModel> Items{get;set;}

    // selected item (from treeview navigation)
    // used for textbox edit
    public ItemViewModel SelectedItem{get;set;}
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    // Used for treeview navigation
    public bool IsSelected{get;set;}
    public bool IsExpanded{get;set;}
    public bool IsInEditNameMode{get;set;}
    public BindingList<ItemViewModel> Children{get;set;}
    public void BuildChildren();

    // Used for treeview display/rename
    // Used for textbox display/rename
    public string Name{get;set;}

    // Used for textbox edit
    public string Content{get;set;}
}
```

This works well for a while.
But as the application grows more complex, the view model gets "polluted" more and more.

For example, adding additional presentations for the same view model (Advanced properties, Graph representation, etc)

```cs
public class ItemViewModel
{
    // Used for Advanced properties
    public BindingList<PropertyEntry> Properties {get;set;}
    public PropertyEntry SelectedProperty{get;set;}

    // Used for graph relationship
    public BindingList<ItemViewModel> GraphSiblings{get;set;}
    public bool IsGraphInEditNameMode{get;set;}
    public bool IsSelectedGraphNode {get;set;}
    public void BuildGraphSiblings();

    // Used for treeview navigation
    public bool IsNavigationInEditNameMode{get;set;}
    public bool IsSelectedNavigationNode{get;set;}
    public bool IsExpandedNavigationNode{get;set;}
    public BindingList<ItemViewModel> NavigationChildren{get;set;}
    public void BuildNavigationChildren();

    // Used for treeview display/rename
    // Used for textbox display/rename
    // Used for graph display
    // Used for Advanced properties display
    public string Name{get;set;}

    // Used for textbox edit
    public string Content{get;set;}
}
```

Currently, I'm still using a single view model for multiple presentations, because it keeps the selected item in-sync across all presentation.

Also, I do not have to keep duplicating properties (Name/Content).

And finally, PropertyChanged notification helps updates all presentation of the item (ie, changing Name in navigation updates TextBox/Graph/Advanced properties/etc).

However, it also feels like a violation of several principles (single responsibility, least privilege, etc).

But I'm not quite sure how to refactor it, without writing a lot of code to keep the sync/property notification working/duplicating the model's properties across each new view model/etc)

What I would like to know:

**If it were up to you, how would you have solved this?**

At the moment, everything is still working. I just feel like the code could be further improved, and that's what I need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could we,

1. try separating-out various view-specific-behaviors from the ItemViewModel class.
2. place/encapsulate the view-specific-behaviors in separate class (Behavior classes).

This gives you flexibility at run-time to instantiate/inject/switch behaviors. 
Yes, try to use Strategy pattern for making a cleaner, single responsible, easy to maintain code.

Comment: Encapsulation definitely sound like a viable solution. I can probably encapsulate the same ItemViewModel instance in presentation-specific view models. That way, I can provide view-specific properties, but still get the sync/notification from the same ItemViewModel instance across all presentations. Will look into this a bit more.

Comment: After much testing, this is the solution that I'm going with. In my case, what I really wanted was "Multiple presentations for the same data object", hence, composition makes more sense than inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

How about using inheritance? Have a basic `ItemViewModel`, then subclass it to create a `TreeViewItemViewModel`, where you add the properties that relate to the tree-view rendering of this item within the subclass.

Comment: Inheritance will solve my duplicate properties problem. But it means I need to instantiate/populate/sync each presentation's view model. I.E, updating TreeItemViewModel.Name will not affect/raise events for GraphItemViewModel.Name, since they'll be different instances. But it does seem like I should find a way to refactor out the common properties